# MySQL Extract multiple values from a XML column and put them into separated columns

Tags: mysql, extract-value

With the following code

`SELECT EXTRACTVALUE('<a><b>x</b><b>y</b><b>z</b></a>', '//b') as 'values'`

I got this:

```
values
x y z
```

But I want this:

```
value_b0 value_b1 value_b2
   x        y        z
```

How?